# mpdf not supporting arabic and chinese fonts

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using mpdf. When I supplied the arabic and chinese words to the WriteHtml(), the resulting pdf containing square boxes instead of those fonts.

Please suggest!

Sample fonts:

```
I am testing أنا العالم 我的世界
```

Answer (score 31):

On mPDF 6.0, we found this made Cantonese work for us:

```
$mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
$mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
```

Seems SetAutoFont is now deprecated.

Comment: I also found that you need `$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = false;`.  Even with the addition of the above modifications.

Answer (score 17):

Add this to your php code:

```
$mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
$mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
```

in css file make sure that you have:

```
font-family: dejavusanscondensed;
direction: rtl;
```

and finly make sure that all **DejaVuSans*.ttf** files are in **ttfonts** folder

Answer (score 5):

You need to enable the support of PDF Asian font like this:

```
$pdf = $this->pdf->load();
$pdf->useAdobeCJK = true;
$pdf->SetAutoFont(AUTOFONT_ALL);
```

Comment: You just saved my evening.

Comment: Spent the whole day debugging that lib, should have googled first.

Comment: from mPDF: function SetAutoFont is depracated as of mPDF 6.  Please use autoScriptToLang insead.  See config.php.  http://www.mpdfonline.com/repos/mpdfmanual.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is pretty late but I've tried this for Arabic language using version 8.x and it worked for me.

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf();
$mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

I needed to add `$mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;` because some fonts don't render arabic and that's where it gets messy with squares, etc.

for more information [here](https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/automatic-font-selection.html#autolangtofont)

Comment: Like in the answer posted 4 years before this?

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at the latest release, version 6?  It contains a lot of upgrades for foreign languages.

Comment: Hi I am using mpdf 7.1, I am using CKEdior to get html from the user, but still It is not supporting. I found the some workaround by applying <span> tag with "fontfamily: arial" declaration its working fine. But we can't expect to insert span to the foreign language...!