# How to display tamil letters using mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf, tamil

```
$html="தனியுரிமை கொள்கை"; $html.= '   <html>   <head>

             $pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$stylesheet = file_get_contents('css/invoice_custom.css'); //$html =
mb_convert_encoding($html, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
$pdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1); $pdf->WriteHTML($html); 
//$pdf->Output('Invoice.pdf','I'); 
$filename="Invoice".rand().".pdf";



$pdf->Output();
```

The code is not displaying tamil characters, how can I fix that?

Comment: I can't personally help with the mpdf/Tamil characters question, but in general you'll get better response on StackOverflow if your code is formatted as a code block (indent by 4 spaces).  As it is it's difficult to read so people will skip it.

Comment: Check out this link https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-5-x.html. It might be related to fonts.

Comment: I have tried the solution as per the above link. Now tamil font is not displayed correctly and english letters are not displayed. Can i show  both tamil and english characters in pdf using mpdf?

Comment: See example file with multiple languages https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf-examples/blob/development/example29_multilingual_autofont.php#L262

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mpdf not supporting arabic and chinese fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221517/mpdf-not-supporting-arabic-and-chinese-fonts)